# I am trying to make each HTML5 element fade in one at a time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is it not working?

```
$eachmultiplechoice = $('.eachmultiplechoice');

$eachmultiplechoice.each(   function(index) 
{   $(this).delay(200*index).fadeIn(300);   }   );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pppun97y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the elements are not hidden. As they are visible `fadeIn` doesn't do anything. Hide them then it will *work*.

```
$eachmultiplechoice.hide().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(200 * index).fadeIn(300);
});
```